# Python & Pandas. Ao tentar retorna apenas 50 registros do pd.read_excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou tentando consultar uma base com diversos nomes de munícipios, porém o código esta retornando apenas 50 registros sendo que a base possui mais de 5.000.

```
filename = fd.askopenfilename() # Consulta o endereço onde esta a planilha
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='base') # Tentativa selecionando quantas linhas consultar nrows=500
    
num_pag = 0
try:
    for municipios in filename:
        arquivo = open('Texto.txt','a') 
        arquivo.write(df['municipios'].loc[num_pag]+'\n') # Tentei registrar em um TXT
        print(df['municipios']) # Tentei imprimir o resultado
        num_pag = num_pag+1
except:
    pass
```

Porém o pandas aparentemente lê apenas os 50 primeiros registros da planilha.

Tentei até mesmo alterar a extensão do arquivo com os dados e determinar o número de linhas que deveria retornar através do parâmetro, ex: nrows=500. Caso eu coloque o parâmetro nrows=1 dentro do pd.read_excel. Ele roda faz o for apenas 1 vez e pega o primeiro registro. Quando coloco mais de 50, ele roda apenas 50.

Comment: Você pode atualizar seu post com parte do conteúdo da planilha?

Comment: Não duplique as publicações https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551207/c%c3%b3digo-retornando-apenas-50-linhas-da-planilha-consultada

Comment: Boa tarde. Na verdade abri outra pois a anterior foi fechada por "falta" de informações. Como não localizei a opção de reabrir, abri um nova.

Comment: Essa publicação não faz sentido existir aqui no site. É um erro grosseiro cujo a causa foi [explicada na duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551207/c%c3%b3digo-retornando-apenas-50-linhas-da-planilha-consultada#comment982960_551207) e resposta não apresenta uma real solução, na verdade não faz sentido e apenas mostra um caminho não recomendável onde o correto seria você editar a pergunta inicial e apresentar um [mcve] que seria uma amostra pequena de dados para testes tanto do problema quanto as soluções.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
while (i_m < 5568):
    try:
       nome = df.loc[i_m, 'muni']

    except:
       pass
```

Desta formar ele fez a varredura em todas as linhas.

Comment: **AVISO:** Essa resposta está equivocada. não é a melhor maneira de se itera pelos elementos duma série e iterando não seria a melhor forma de salvar uma toda uma coluna dum dataframe num arquivo de texto. Para salvar uma coluna num arquivo texto vejam [`pandas.Series.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) ou [`pandas.Series.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html)

Comment: Compreendo que pode não ser a maneira correta ou a melhor maneira, porém funcionou. Posteriormente tentarei deixar o código mais límpido e com a estrutura mais integra. Quando conseguir, compartilho aqui. Obg.

Comment: Isso está tudo errado, para fazer o que quer só precisa destas três linhas `>>>filename = fd.askopenfilename()`,`>>>df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='base')` e `>>>df['municipios'].to_csv("teste.txt", header=False)`